# Elasticsearch cluster configuration in an AWS region with only two availability zones

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have to setup an ElasticSearch cluster in a AWS region which has only 2 availability zones.

I want to make it so that in case one zone becomes unavailable the cluster still works correctly. Meaning it accepts reads and writes and does not go into the "split brain" mode.

I know I have to consider `minimum_master_nodes` setting, but I find it tricky how to distribute the master eligible nodes cross 2 zones only (with 3 zones would have been easier).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is really only one way to manage a cluster across two availability zones: you must set it up so that you can survive one zone failing, but not the other. In other words, you should not setup your master nodes so that both sides can survive if they are disconnected from each other because you will guarantee a split-brain situation, which will result in some data loss.

Assuming you have 3 eligible master nodes, you should put **two masters in one zone (the one that is more robust historically)** - let's call it zone A - **and one master in the other zone** - let's call it zone B.

You could setup also a standby master node that is kept configured and powered off in zone B, so if zone A were to "disappear" then this other master can be powered up to maintain the optimal minimum masters (meaning 2) and allow the cluster to keep operating. No other way around this.

Comment: Thanks Andrei. This really helps.

Comment: So what you're implying is that with 3 eligible masters in 2 AZs, you can only have the option of A) Zero fault tolerance (min master 2), or B) Split brain (min master 1)? So you might as well just have 1 master node?

Comment: Actually, it occurred to me recently that you can have one data node to also act as a master. So in availability zone 1 we have 2 nodes (one master and one master+data node) and in zone 2 he have 2 nodes (one master and one data node). @Andrei, what do you think would this work?